# Parsing a text file of integers into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgets, strtok

I'm using [strtok()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) to parse each integer and place it into `int nums[1000]`. The file will always follow the format of:

the first line has the numbers for the array, each separated by spaces. No more than 10 numbers will be on the line. Nothing is in the file after the first line.

```
printf("Starting program\n");
char file_name[100];
strcpy(file_name, args[1]);
char number[100];
strcpy(number, args[2]);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}
char int_array[1000];//
int nums[1000]; //storing the integers without spaces
int i = 0; //for indexing the array to save the integers
while (fgets(int_array, 1000, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", "test");
    puts(int_array); // prints out `1 2 3 4 5...`
    char *token;
    token = strtok(int_array, " ");
    nums[i] = atoi(token);
    while (token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        nums[i] = atoi(token);
        //puts(token); Token gets printed out correctly.
    }
}

printf("%i\n", nums[i]); // this gives segmentation fault
printf(nums) // also gives seg fault
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting seg fault.

Comment: Are you really not incrementing `i` at all or have you just left that out? If `i` really is 0 then I don't believe that `printf("%i\n", nums[i])` will segfault. That is not possible. But the next line will definetely be an issue as it is totally invalid - you can't just call `printf` anway you like. Read the man page and check what parameters it takes. Use a debugger to find out exactly which line is segfaulting and examine the variable values.

Comment: what is the value of `i` at the bottom when you do: `printf("%i\n", nums[i]);`?  If it's over 999 that could be a clue to the seg fault

Comment: aaah yes i modified the code and accidently left out ++i. I'm still working on figuring out the seg fault. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code, the main issue is you test `token` **before** scanning the next token:

```
while (token != NULL) {
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    nums[i] = atoi(token);
}
```

You should instead do this:

```
while ((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
    nums[i] = atoi(token);
}
```

Other issues:

- You do not check if `argc > 1` before accessing `argv[1]` in `strcpy(file_name, args[1]);`, potentially invoking undefined behavior.
- You copy the file name into a 100 byte array: if the command line argument is longer than 99 bytes, you are causing a buffer overflow. You do not need to copy the argument, just pass `argv[1]` to `fopen` or use a pointer: `char *filename = argv[1];`
- You check if `fopen()` failed, but do not exit the function... `fgets()` has undefined behavior for a null stream pointer.
- `strtok()` can return `NULL` even for the first call. Always check the return value before passing it to `atoi()`.
- You do not check if `i` becomes too large. You should stop reading the input file if `i` reaches `1000`.
- Passing the `nums` array to `printf` is incorrect: `printf(nums)` should not even compile, or at least generate meaningful warnings.

Note that you do not need to use `strtok()` at all. `strtol()` can parse a number and update a pointer to point past the number.

Here is how to use that:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Starting program\n");
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing command line argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[1000];
    int nums[1000];
    int i = 0; 

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        char *p = buf;
        char *q;
        for (; i < 1000; i++) {
            nums[i] = strtol(p, &q, 0);
            if (q == p) {
                /* no more numbers */
                break;
            }
            p = q;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%d ", nums[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing the use of token as you mentioned got the seg fault so stop. Thanks a lot. Do you mind explaining what the exact difference is from your implementation and mine?

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking `argc` and derefencing `args[1]` and `args[2]`.

You never use `number`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
   printf("Starting program\n");
   if( argc < 2 ) {
      return 1;
   }
   FILE * fp = fopen( argv[1], "r");
   if( fp == NULL ) {
      perror( argv[1] );
      return 1;
   }
   char int_array[1000];
   if( fgets( int_array, 1000, fp )) {
      int nums[1000];
      int    i = 0; 
      char * token = strtok(int_array, " ");
      while( token ) {
         nums[i++] = atoi(token);
         token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
      printf("0: %i\n", nums[0]);
      printf("1: %i\n", nums[1]);
      printf("%d: %i\n", i-1, nums[i-1]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
aubin@Breizh-Atao ~/Dev/C $ gcc parsing.c -o parsing
aubin@Breizh-Atao ~/Dev/C $ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 >parsing.txt
aubin@Breizh-Atao ~/Dev/C $ ./parsing parsing.txt 
Starting program
0: 1
1: 2
10: 11
aubin@Breizh-Atao ~/Dev/C $
```